# Validity, reliability and repeatability

Tags: reliability, validity, repeatability

I want to validate an anemometer in a wind tunnel VS gold standard.

Thinking in validity, reliability and repeatability.

The dependent variable is wind speed. I can test 3 different units of the same model of anemometer if it´s necessary.

My question is if it’s possible to do reliability. All that I could read about the reliability talk about different subjects, but in this case, do the variability of use depend of the subject doesn´t exist, like with a scale for example, that depend on the weight but not on the person that use it.